# How to use OpenAPI's typescript-axios' functional programming interface in Vue?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios, functional-programming, openapi

I am using OpenAPI's typescript-axios generator. The resulting api.ts file includes 3 different implementations (interfaces) for each REST endpoint:

- factory interface
- object-oriented interface
- functional programming interface

For my ProductController I tried out all three:

```
onMounted(() => {
  // Using the factory interface
  ProductControllerApiFactory().productGet().then(axiosResponse => {
    console.log('Factory', axiosResponse.data);
  });

  // Using the object-oriented interface
  new ProductControllerApi().productGet().then(axiosResponse => {
    console.log('Class', axiosResponse.data);
  });

  // Using the functional programming interface
  ProductControllerApiFp().productGet().then(axiosPromise => {
    axiosPromise().then(res => {
      console.log('Functional', res.data)
    })
  });
});
```

All three work as intended, but I was wondering about the last one's return type. **What is the benefit of returning an AxiosPromise? In this case I need to call then() twice.**

I am probably not thinking in "functional programming" - what are the use cases here? To me this creates unnecessary boiler plate code